# ArcAnimation on Imageview creates bit of jerk android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to move Imageview in curved path to a particular point. So I make use of this [library](https://github.com/asyl/ArcAnimator). I have to move the imageview in the curved path and the image view should return to its original position. This is one cycle. But it should repeat indefinitely until I press a button in that activity.

It works as expected but when the imageview finishes one cycle and about to start the next cycle, the image view is shaken little bit at the starting point (This is not happening for the first time but it happens for second and so forth) and then the animation proceeds normally.

```
private fun startAnimation(thermView: ImageView, thermAnimIdentifierView: TextView) {
    Log.d(TAG, "****************************************************Start Animation")
    val arcAnimator = ArcAnimator.createArcAnimator(thermView, thermAnimIdentifierView, 360f, Side.RIGHT)
    arcAnimator.setDuration(5000)
    arcAnimator.setInterpolator(CycleInterpolator(0.5f))


    arcAnimator.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
            val arcAnimator = ArcAnimator.createArcAnimator(thermView, thermAnimIdentifierView, 360f, Side.RIGHT)
            arcAnimator.setStartDelay(500)
            arcAnimator.setDuration(5000)
            arcAnimator.setInterpolator(CycleInterpolator(0.5f))
            arcAnimator.addListener(this)
            arcAnimator.start()
        }

        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {
        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator) {
        }
    })
    arcAnimator.start()
}
```

Comment: so dont use that library, with `PathMeasure` you can do it by yourself in 10 minutes

Comment: Can you pls post some example?

Comment: example of PathMeasure?

Comment: Example of this animation

Comment: use a `TimeAnimator` "his class provides a simple callback mechanism to listeners that is synchronized with all other animators in the system. There is no duration, interpolation, or object value-setting with this Animator. Instead, it is simply started, after which it proceeds to send out events on every animation frame to its TimeListener (if set), with information about this animator, the total elapsed time, and the elapsed time since the previous animation frame."